# How to include required jars in project while using Maven?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I am new to `Maven` and using it to build a project on my local. This is working nicely on my local. Now, I want to run the same project on my server and the server does not have `Maven` installed. So I wanted to ask if there is any way by which, when I build a `Maven` project on my local, I could include all the required jars in it and then simply transfer it to my server? I know `Maven` creates the `repository` in `C:\Documents and Settings\username\.m2 on Windows`.

But how can I include all the `jars` in project the way we do traditionally? I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164043/maven-how-to-include-jars-which-are-not-available-in-reps-into-a-j2ee-project). But it talks about creating a custom repository and I don't have Maven installed at all. so I guess it is not a suitable solution to me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Maven collect all the dependent JARs for a project to help with application deployment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567996/can-maven-collect-all-the-dependent-jars-for-a-project-to-help-with-application-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html). From the documentation:

> The Assembly Plugin for Maven is primarily intended to allow users to aggregate the project output along with its dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files into a single distributable archive.